# Using two inputs fields with three functions for one output

Tags: javascript, html, output

I use two functions to process two inputs and then have a third function to compare the results with the result of the third function being the output.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="standardPremuimcalc" oninput="updateOutput()">
    <input name= "new_loan_amount" type="number" value="0"/>
    <input name= "purchase_price" type="number" value="0"/>
    <output name= "premuim_rate" for="new loan amount purchase price"></output>
</form>
```

Here is my js:

```
function updateOutput(){

var form = document.getElementById("standardPremiumcalc");
var out = form.elements["premium_rate"];
var amount = parseInt(form.elements["new_loan_amount"].value);
var purchase = parseInt(form.elements ["purchase_price"].value);
var loanCalc = lender()
var ownCalc = owner()

function lender(amount){
if (amount<=100000){
    if (amount<=40000){
        return 200;
    }else{
        return (Math.ceil(amount/1000))*5;
    }
}else{
    if ((amount-100000)<=500000){
        return 500+(Math.ceil((amount-100000)/1000)*3.95);
    }else if ((amount-500000)<=2000000) {
        return 2080+(Math.ceil((amount-500000)/1000)*2.65);
    }else{
        return 6055+(Math.ceil((amount-2000000)/1000)*2);
    }
} 
}
function owner(purchase) {
if (purchase<=100000){
    if (purchase<=40000){
        return 200;
    }else{
        return (Math.ceil(purchase/1000))*5;
    }
}else{
    if ((purchase-100000)<=500000){
        return 500+(Math.ceil((purchase-100000)/1000)*3.95);
    }else if ((purchase-500000)<=2000000) {
        return 2080+(Math.ceil((purchase-500000)/1000)*2.65);
    }else{
        return 6055+(Math.ceil((purchase-2000000)/1000)*2);
    }
} 
}
function standardPremium (loanCalc,ownCalc) {
    if (loanCalc-ownCalc>0) {
        out.value = loanCalc+ownCalc
    }else{
        out.value = loanCalc
}
}
    lender(amount)
    owner(purchase)
    standardPremium(loanCalc,ownCalc)
};
```

I am not getting an output field, what am I missing?

Comment: I created another function that is activated on input and calls standardPremium (lender(amount),owner(purchase)) which then made my JS run.

Answer (score 0):

`premuim_rate` needs to be `premium_rate` in your HTML

Comment: good eye thanks, i changed premuim to premium in my HTML but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

first: your form id has the same misspelling.

second: you don't pass an **amount** variable to your two functions **lender** and **owner**.

Comment: Fixed the misspelling already. I thought I was passing an amount variable when I declared the variables amount and purchase and use the parseInt command to get the value from the form